# Formatted NSLocalizedString with variable value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I'm new to Objective-C. Here is my question:

In my two string files are the following two entries:

(German string file)

```
/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Import to DoS"; ObjectID = "GfF-rD-aDa"; */
"GfF-rD-aDa.text" = "Zu DT %lu importieren";
```

(English string file)

```
/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Import to DoS"; ObjectID = "GfF-rD-aDa"; */
    "GfF-rD-aDa.text" = "Import to DoS %lu";
```

My code looks like:

```
self.importLabel.text = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"GfF-rD-aDa.text", nil), projectday];
```

According to Apples Documentation [NSLocalizedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedString) needs a key and a comment. That's why I putted @"GfF-rD-aDa.text" into the first parameter because it's the same key like in my strings file.

So I want it to generate strings like:

```
"Zu DT 2 importieren"
```

and

```
"Import to DoS 2"
```

but it doesn't work. The output text is:

```
"GfF-rD-aDa.text"
```

I'm not allowed to change the key in the strings table because we use a script to generate all these entries based on the object id.

Regards

Comment: if the localized string has not been found for the current language in the localization string then the key will be presented. why do you have two different value for the same key in the same file?

Comment: @holex like I said: "In my two string files are the following two entries". I have two files for English and German. But I agree with you, I should have put them in separated code blocks for better understanding. Will change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this specify your strings file in NSLocalizedStringFromTable macro.

```
 self.importLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"GfF-rD-aDa.text", @"yourStringsFile", @"comment"), projectday];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.importLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"GfF-rD-aDa.text", nil), projectday];
```